# Crystal Report Calculating Variable Context

Tags: crystal-reports

I Created a Variable in Crystal to Calculate a Unique Count of Two sets of Data which gives out the Grand Unique count of one set

Now If I have to use this Variable in a Group to get Group Unique Count what as to be added to the variable to get the Group Count and not the Grand Count

```
  Distinct AB Count = DISTINCTCOUNT({@AE AB Count})- COUNT({@Total of AE})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to any summary function in Crystal specifies the group level you want the summary to work over. For example,

`numbervar distinctCountForGroup := distinctcount({table.fieldYouAreSummarizing},{table.fieldYouAreGroupingOn});`